# Установка timestamp property в maven

Tags: maven

Столкнулся с задачей сделать resource filtering и пробросить время билда в виде timestamp (т.е. числа секунд или миллисекунд начиная с linux epoch time), и не понимаю, как это сделать. Большинство плагинов предлагают обертку над SimpleDateFormat, который (насколько понял) не поддерживает форматирование в виде timestamp. Как я могу решить эту проблему?

Comment: [Build Number](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/), если формат не указывать, пишет в `${timestamp}` в миллисекундах.

Comment: @zRrr судя по сорсам - должен, но не пишет, уже пробовал его